# How to define a return-path using nodejs nodemailer?

Tags: nodemailer, return-path

I use nodemailer to send emails but I need to define the Return-Path.

I define in the address `from`, `replyTo` and also `returnPath`.

The returnPath (Return-Path) is writen like this: `<bla@somewhere.com>`

But it does not work. It always changes the `Return-Path` in the source code of the messages on the email server address. Any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the envelope property

```js
const mailOptions = {
    envelope: {
      'from': '<your@return-path.com>',
      'to': "detination@email.com"
    },
    from: "Info <foo@example.com>",
    to: "detination@email.com",
    subject: "....",
    text: "Hello world",
    html: "<b>Hello world ✔</b>",
}

sendMail(mailOptions);
```

Do not omit the "< >"